# Handling <class 'nltk.corpus.reader.wordlist.WordListCorpusReader'> in Python

Tags: python, nltk, word-cloud

I am using the "wordcloud" package in Python and trying to ingest my own tri-lingual (English, French and German) stopword list.

This "EN_FR_DE" stopword list is stored in the NLTK data folder alongside the standard NLTK stopword lists on my PC because I am using it in other contexts, too. I would now like to import this custom stopword list, turn it into a string and use it in "wordcloud". I used "string" to convert the list. When I check its "type", however, the output still is:

```
<class 'nltk.corpus.reader.wordlist.WordListCorpusReader'>
```

Of course, "wordcloud" does not accept this list and ignores all the stopwords (see graph image linked below).

**I wasn't even aware that this was a class of its own, and I could not find instructions how to handle this particular type of class. What is the proper way to convert it into a string?**

My full script for building the wordcloud is:

```
# Generate word cloud from publication titles in English, French and German

from wordcloud import WordCloud
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import string
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

infile=("C:\\Users\\mobarget\\Google Drive\\ACADEMIA\\Metadata_PhD\\BritishRiots_TopicModel\\British_riots_text.txt")  

# define stopwords and convert them to string

stopwords_multiling=' '.join(stopwords.words('en_fr_de'))
print(stopwords_multiling[:50])
print(type(stopwords))

# read and pre-process data

with open(infile, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f: # open file
    data1=f.read() # read content of file as string
    data2=data1.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)).lower() # remove punctuation
    data3=' '.join(data2.split()) # remove additional whitespace from text

# define word cloud layout

wordcloud = WordCloud(width = 800, height = 800, 
                background_color ='white', 
                stopwords = stopwords_multiling, 
                min_font_size = 10).generate(data3) 

# plot the WordCloud image   

plt.figure(figsize = (8, 8), facecolor = None) 
plt.imshow(wordcloud, interpolation="bilinear") 
plt.axis("off") 
plt.tight_layout(pad = 0) 

plt.show()
```

And this is the output:

```
i me my myself we our ours ourselves you you're yo
<class 'nltk.corpus.reader.wordlist.WordListCorpusReader'>
```

[Graph Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJjOg.png)

Comment: I'm fairly sure that the `stopwords` parameter is supposed to be a container/iterable of strings, not one giant string, or else it treats it as a container of individual characters. So you should just be able to pass that `stopwords` object directly, or maybe convert it to a set, `set(stopwords)`

Comment: Passing it directly did not work, unfortunately, and one tutorial online said a string was required, but your idea to convert it to a set sounds much more reasonable. Thanks so much. I will try.

Comment: I have finally found the revelant paragraph in the official-official documentation:

**stopwords: set of strings or None**

Here is the link for everyone who is interested: [amueller.github.io](https://amueller.github.io/word_cloud/generated/wordcloud.WordCloud.html)